# How to include dynamic HTML in a form?

Tags: webforms

I am building a form using data so it will be dynamic. I have done all the work in a PHP only way eg. I have built the HTML dynamically including checkboxes which need to be submitted as a form.

My question is how do I include the HTML to pass to the screen in a dynamic form?

eg.

```
$result1 = db_query('select tid, name from {taxonomy_term_data} where vid = :uid order by tid', array(':uid' => '6'));
$str = '';

foreach ($result1 as $record1) {
    //get date ordered request for each course
    $result2 = db_query('select * from {pd_course_request} where course_description_vocab_id = :tid order by timestamp', array(':tid' => $record1->tid));
    $str .= '<h1>' . $record1->name . '</h1>';
    if($result2->rowCount()>0){
        $str .= '<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Resolved</td>
                    </tr>';

        //list all request data
        foreach ($result2 as $record2) {
            $str .=     '<tr>
                        <td class="pd_table_data">' . gmdate("d / m / Y H:i:s", $record2->timestamp) . '</td>
                        <td class="pd_table_data">' . $record2->name . '</td>
                        <td class="pd_table_data">' . $record2->email . '</td>
                        <td class="pd_table_data">' . --A DYNAMIC CHECKBOX HERE-- . '</td>';
        }
ETC. ETC. ETC.....
return $str;
```

Will building a form this way work?
How do I pass the dynamic fields and HTML back if not?

cheers,
George

Comment: No it won't work like that, the FAPI won't be able to process input data for fields it doesn't know about. You need to use the [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to build the form, and theme the elements to get them into a table (e.g. http://passingcuriosity.com/2011/drupal-7-forms-tables/)

Comment: Thats great! Just what I was looking for, thank you.